# How to initialize pointers in a linked list to templated class to NULL in constructor implemented in header file

Tags: c++, data-structures, constructor, linked-list, iterator

Hello I am working on a project for data structures and I am stuck. 
The project is to build a templated linked list class and a nested iterator class, inside a headerfile only. I do not understand how to use the iterator class inside of the templated LinkedList class. I am not sure about iterators in general. The methods declared are all needed to run the tests that will be ran. I am currently stuck on initializing 'LinkedList* prev' and next in the constructor. Please help! How do I initialize something that is templated? the compiler wants to know what data type I think? Thanks for your time
The error is on the constructor declaration in the class LinkedList 
EDITED "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::basic_string char&' from an rvalue of type 'int'" is the error message

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H_
#define LINKEDLIST_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
template <typename T> class  LinkedList
{

    private:
        LinkedList<T>* head;
        int size;
        T element = NULL;
        LinkedList<T>* prev;
        LinkedList<T>* next;
    public:


        class Iterator
        {
                friend class LinkedList<T>;
            private:

            public:
                Iterator();
                T operator*() const;
                Iterator& operator++();
                bool operator==(Iterator const& rhs);
                bool operator!=(Iterator const& rhs);
        };

        LinkedList<T>():prev(0), next(0){} //HERE is the ERROR????////////
        Iterator begin() const
        {
 //         Iterator tempIterator = LinkedList<T>();
//
//          return tempIterator->front;
            return NULL;
        }
        Iterator end() const{return NULL;}
        bool isEmpty() const;
        T getFront() const;
        T getBack() const;
        void enqueue(T newElement)
        {
            LinkedList<T>* newElem = new LinkedList<T>();
            newElem->element = newElement;
            if(front == 0)
            {
                front = newElem;
            }
            else
            {
                 back->next = newElem;
            }
            back = newElem;
            listSize++;
         }
        void dequeue()
        {
            LinkedList<T>* tempElem = new LinkedList<T>();
            if(front == 0){
                cout << "List is empty!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                tempElem = front;
                front = front->next;
                cout << "the element dequeued: " << tempElem->element;
                delete tempElem;
            }
        }
        void pop();
        void clear();
        bool contains(T element) const;
        void remove(T element);

    };





#endif /* LINKEDLIST_H_ */
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that reproduces the error. Post error messages verbatim please.

Comment: `front`, `back` and `listSize` are not declared. Where do they come from?

Comment: If your instructor told you that it's a good idea to `use namespace std;`, and even better idea to stick that into a header file, then you need to [immediately find a better instructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). You're being taught bad programming habits that will only work against you, if you truly intend to have a career in computer programming.

Comment: Assuming this is just for academic instruction (because you'd be insane not to use `std::list`, `std::deque`, or `std::vector` if it isn't), do yourself a favor and create a `Node` nested class inside `LinkedList`. A chain of *those* is what will hold your elements and their fore-and-aft pointers. nested like your iterator class. The `LinkedList` itself just contains the head pointer, the tail pointer, some sizing info, etc. As is now, each node in the list is carrying around it's own *head* pointer, which doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: **WHAT** error? Where is the error message you're asking about?

Comment: i will change using namespace std thank you, "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::basic_string char&' from an rvalue of type 'int'" is the error message, I left out what I know how to fix. I am an online student, this is my second time using this.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig, I was thinking node struct, but a class?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor syntax is wrong.

```
LinkedList():prev(0), next(0){}
```

This is the correct constructor syntax. Once the `template` class and parameters are declared, in the `template` declaration, the name of the template alone, without the parameters, refers to the template itself, inside its scope. Similarly, if you were to explicitly define a destructor, it would be:

```
~LinkedList() { /* ... */ }
```

If you wanted to only declare the constructor inside the template declaration:

```
 LinkedList();
```

and then define it outside of the template declaration, then the correct syntax would be:

```
template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() :prev(0), next(0){}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue here? At least gcc does not complain about either `LinkedList()` or `LinkedList<T>()` and I think the standard requires in §12.1.1 only a class-name referring to the current istantiation, which by §14.6.2.1.1 may include the template argument list. I am not very familiar with the standard though.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the error is "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::basic_string char&' from an rvalue of type 'int'

Comment: Constructor works now, thanks again! you rock

Comment: I added a node class as suggested above, it contains T element, LinkedList<t> prev, and LinkedList<t> next, how could I create a constructor the way you suggested? I tried just a Node constructor inside of the node class, then I tried template<typename T> LinkedList<T>::Node() : element(), prev(0), next(0) , I also tried ...Node::Node()... used the same way